# PDFsharp 1.50 beta 3: Empty owner password error when adding password to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, passwords, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I'm exploring the PDFsharp library and am having issues password protecting PDFs.

Following this example on their website http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=36&Itemid=47,

Here is my code

```
 try
 {
   string filename = "hi.pdf";
   File.Copy(Path.Combine("C:/User/Ichigo/Desktop", filename),
   Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename), true);

   PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(filename, "some text");

   PdfSecuritySettings securitySettings = document.SecuritySettings;

   securitySettings.UserPassword="user";
   securitySettings.OwnerPassword="owner";

   securitySettings.PermitAccessibilityExtractContent = false;
   securitySettings.PermitAnnotations = false;
   securitySettings.PermitAssembleDocument = false;
   securitySettings.PermitExtractContent = false;
   securitySettings.PermitFormsFill = true;
   securitySettings.PermitFullQualityPrint = false;
   securitySettings.PermitModifyDocument = true;
   securitySettings.PermitPrint = false;

   document.Save(filename);
 }
 catch (Exception e) 
 { throw new Exception("Something went wrong : " + e); }
```

Whenever I add the code that sets the passwords:

```
securitySettings.UserPassword="user";
securitySettings.OwnerPassword="owner";
```

I get `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when I reach the line that saves the PDF

document.Save(filename);
I'm also getting error messages

```
---- DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED ----
---- Assert Short Message ----
Empty owner password.
---- Assert Long Message ----

   at PdfSharp.Pdf.Security.PdfStandardSecurityHandler.PrepareEncryption() in c:\Users\Ichigo\Downloads\PDFsharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_50-beta3b\PDFsharp\src\PdfSharp\Pdf.Security\PdfStandardSecurityHandler.cs:line 590
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.DoSave(PdfWriter writer) in c:\Users\Ichigo\Downloads\PDFsharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_50-beta3b\PDFsharp\src\PdfSharp\Pdf\PdfDocument.cs:line 392
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.Save(Stream stream, Boolean closeStream) in c:\Users\Ichigo\Downloads\PDFsharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_50-beta3b\PDFsharp\src\PdfSharp\Pdf\PdfDocument.cs:line 325
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.Save(Stream stream) in c:\Users\Ichigo\Downloads\PDFsharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_50-beta3b\PDFsharp\src\PdfSharp\Pdf\PdfDocument.cs:line 352
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.Save(String path) in c:\Users\Ichigo\Downloads\PDFsharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_50-beta3b\PDFsharp\src\PdfSharp\Pdf\PdfDocument.cs:line 258
```

Why am I getting these errors?

Edit- here's the stack trace for the `System.NullReferenceException.`

```
Something went wrong : `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`     
 at PdfSharp.Pdf.Security.PdfStandardSecurityHandler.SetHashKey(PdfObjectID id)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfWriter.WriteBeginObject(PdfObject obj)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDictionary.WriteObject(PdfWriter writer)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage.WriteObject(PdfWriter writer)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.DoSave(PdfWriter writer)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.Save(Stream stream, Boolean closeStream)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.Save(Stream stream)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.Save(String path)
```

Comment: You only get one error message: "System.NullReferenceException". You do not show a stack trace for that error. Does the error occur with all PDF files, e.g. the HelloWorld.pdf that ships with the sample code? If not, please provide your Hi.pdf to make the error reproducible. Do you get the assertion message after the error message? The message that shows first must be investigated first.

Comment: I didn't think to check the PDFs, as you suspected, the error does not occur with HelloWorld.pdf. Here is Hi.pdf https://www.dropbox.com/s/tby9bvw2h60xyj1/hi.pdf?dl=0. I get the assertion message before the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there is a problem with PDFsharp 1.50 beta 3. Nothing wrong with your code.

For a quick fix, you can download the PDFsharp source code and make the following change:

In file "PdfDocument.cs" in method "void DoSave(PdfWriter writer)" look for "// HACK: Remove XRefTrailer" (around line 375) and change it like this (7 new lines replace 2 old lines):

```
// HACK: Remove XRefTrailer
if (_trailer is PdfCrossReferenceStream)
{
    // HACK^2: Preserve the SecurityHandler.
    PdfStandardSecurityHandler securityHandler = _securitySettings.SecurityHandler;
    _trailer = new PdfTrailer((PdfCrossReferenceStream) _trailer);
    _trailer._securityHandler = securityHandler;
}
```

Disclaimer: I tested this with Hi.pdf and HelloWorld.pdf only. While I do hope the new code will never behave worse than the old version, there is no guarantee.

Future versions of PDFsharp, newer than PDFsharp 1.50 beta 3, should not require this patch.